# starting MySql on fedora

Tags: linux, mysql, fedora, rdbms

To install *MySql* I tried this after downloading the rpm package from the official website :

```
yum install MySQL-server-5.5.27-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm
```

Everything went fine and process was completed but now how do I start this RDMS  ? I don't see any icon created in the application tab in fedora 16. I am not sure if everything went fine.

Even if I need to check that is it installed properly how do I check and if installed properly how do I start MySql ?

### Edit :

- Output of `rpm -ql MySQL-server` --> package MySQL-server is not
  installed
- Output of `service mysqld start` ---> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service

*Note :* I also used this : `yum install mysql-server` and at the end got a success message : `Installed:
  mysql-server.i686 0:5.5.27-1.fc16`

Comment: `ls /etc/init.d | grep -i mysql`?

Comment: @quanta what is this ?

Comment: To check the name of the init script.

Comment: @quanta displays nothing

Comment: To query files in this package `rpm -ql MySQL-server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yum install mysql-server (is how you install the version in the repo)
service mysqld start (is how you start is, you can also use /etc/init.d/mysqld start)
chkconfig mysqld on (makes sure it starts when you reboot the server)
```

Comment: when I enter the command `service mysqld start` I get this message _Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details._ Why do I get this ?

Comment: The way I installed _mysql_ is incorrect ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta You installed a MySQL package from a source other than Fedora. You should consult the packager for their documentation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton shall I re-install it using the command given in the answer

Comment: `systemctl status mysqld.service`? `tail -f /var/log/messages`?

Comment: @quanta now what does that do ?

Comment: _See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details._

Comment: @quanta gives out this message `mysqld.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)` for _systemctl status mysqld.service'_

Comment: @quanta how do I open the gui for mysql ? I don't know if the server started but I see this message `Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service` when I type this command `service mysqld start`

Comment: @SuhailGupta: append the output of `rpm -ql MySQL-server` to your original question.

Comment: @quanta **package MySQL-server is not installed** : output

Comment: @SuhailGupta: what about the output of `yum install MySQL-server-5.5.27-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm`?

Comment: @quanta see the edits. I also did `yum install mysql-server`

Comment: @SuhailGupta: have you tried `service mysqld start` again?

Comment: @quanta yeah and I get the message as stated

Comment: `Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service` --> anything else? `ps -ef | grep mysql`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5889/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-quanta)